# How do I connect to MySql from Genymotion

Tags: c#, mysql, xamarin, genymotion

I installed mysql on machine.
I installed GenyMotion Android Emulator
I use the Xamarin MySQL Connector in my Xamarin App.
How do I connect to the mysql database from the Xamarin App running in Genymotion?

Note using 127.0.0.1 as an IP address WON'T work for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

**Your app shouldn't talk directly to the database server. Going through an API is a better approach.**

Now that we got this out of the way here's a short example taken from [here](https://components.xamarin.com/view/mysql-plugin):

```
try
{
    string connectionString = "Server=your.ip.address;Port=3306;database=YOUR_DATA_BASE;User Id=root;Password=password;charset=utf8";
    MySqlConnection  sqlconn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    sqlconn.Open();
    string queryString = "select count(0) from ACCOUNT";
    MySqlCommand sqlcmd = new MySqlCommand(queryString, sqlconn);
    String result = sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    // do something  with the results
    sqlconn.Close();
} catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine (ex.Message);
}
```

You should be able to get the IP address to use from the virtual network adapter created by GenyMotion (which uses VirtualBox)